# How to import component as a module in angular 8

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express

i am making dynamic form with the help of give link :- https://medium.com/@mail.bahurudeen/create-a-dynamic-form-with-configurable-fields-and-validations-using-angular-6-994db56834da

**Error:-**

'dynamic-form' is not a known element:
1. If 'dynamic-form' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'dynamic-form' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message.

but the dynamic-form is not importing

```
                     ts
@Component({
 exportAs: "dynamicForm", 
 selector: 'app-dynamic-form',
 templateUrl: './dynamic-form.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./dynamic-form.component.scss']
})     

@ViewChild(DynamicFormComponent, { static: false }) form: DynamicFormComponent;

                     html

<div class="form">
  <div style="text-align:center">
    <h1>
      Registration Form
    </h1>
  </div>
  <dynamic-form (submit)="submit($event)">
    <!-- [fields]="regConfig" -->
  </dynamic-form>
  <div class="margin-top">
    {{ form.value | json }}
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please edit your question to ensure all the key details are covered - right now it reads like several details are missing. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you imported it in a module?

Comment: @Simon.S.A. FYI you can write `[ask]` to produce this : [ask]. it also works for `[mcve]` !

Comment: Find and use some new tutorial version. More like angular 7 no angular 6. In Your tutorial the guy showing You how to import modules. He creates one called `material.module.ts` specially for `@angular/material` components/modules and import them, then export them to `app.module.ts`.

Comment: In the tutorial ( given link ) there is no need add module.